# None of the rails  command  working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Whenever I am trying to start the server by using  the following command:-

```
/Demo$ rails s
```

It is showing me that the I have invalid dates.

```
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid   
date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z"

Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date                    
format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"**strong text**

Could not find tilt-1.3.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

And I have also mentioned the gem in  my gemfile and have ran the bundle install.

Same apply  to rails c command, rake commands etc.

Thanks for your help